# How to "quit" DFG Eigene Stelle and transfer the funding to another person?

Tags: funding, job-search, germany, early-career

The Deutsche Forschungsgemeinschaft (DFG), which funds most basic research in Germany, has a grant program that funds a temporary position ("Eigene Stelle") for novice principal investigators (PIs) who have completed their PhD.

If a PI is funded by the Eigene Stelle program and receives a different position outside of Germany, is it possible to "quit" the Eigene Stelle and "transfer" the associated funding to a different person (e.g. PhD student or Postdoc)?

Comment: Have you asked your grant provider about the conditions of this funding scheme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With 5 minutes of googling I find the second to last question in https://www.dfg.de/en/research_funding/faq/faq_temporary_positions/index.html (which is the english version of https://www.dfg.de/foerderung/faq/eigene_stelle_faq/index.html) :

> As a principal investigator I am being promoted and I have been offered a move to another position. What options do I have for continuing my project?

> You can easily continue your project from another site, whether at the same institution or a different one. If it is no longer possible for you to devote sufficient time to your project in your new position due to other commitments, you can use the funds earmarked for the temporary position for principal investigator to hire additional personnel. Please contact the DFG Head Office.

I am not entirely sure how this applies to positions outside of Germany, but if you contact them, they should know.

Comment: I would be quite confident that this also applied to positions in AT and CH, but likely not outside.